# Intercept X11 KeyPress event in GtkDrawingArea of GTK+3 on Linux

Tags: gtk, x11, gtk3

GTK+ version: 3.18.9

I created a drawing area (GtkWidget) with following code

```
content = gtk_drawing_area_new();
gtk_widget_set_can_focus(content, TRUE);
gtk_widget_add_events(content, GDK_ALL_EVENTS_MASK);
g_signal_connect(content, "draw", G_CALLBACK(&drawCallback), ctx);
gtk_widget_realize(content);

// Add a filter for interception
gdk_window_add_filter(content, gtk_widget_get_window(content),
  OnXEvent, NULL);
```

Problem is that when I clicked the wideget, I got sequence of XEvents as follows:

```
LeaveNotify
FocusIn
EnterNotify
ButtonPress
FocusOut    // Lost focus!
ButtonRelease
```

Above **FocusOut** indicated we lost focus right away after clicking. 
It implies we can't receive any keyboard events since they are available only within focus.

Is this limitation of GTK? If not, is there any tools/methodlogy to find out which widget/widow trigger the FocusOut?

References:

[gdk_window_add_filter](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-add-filter)

Comment: Well, what's the value of the FocusOut event's `detail` field? Also, could you print the `window` field of all events here just to see if all these events are sent to the same window?

Comment: Can you please explain how you implemented the ```OnXEvent``` function. I am trying conditionally translate a left / right arrow key press to SHIT+TAB / TAB. Even if I completely fill the GdkEvent union all I get is the following warning at runtime. "Gdk-WARNING **: 13:16:43.246: Event with type 8 not holding a GdkDevice. It is most likely synthesized outside Gdk/GTK+"

Answer (score 0):

As of GTK+ version 3.18.9, it uses an extra X window for toplevel window and any keyboard events are captured by the window. Thus a filter need to be added as a global one, i.e.

`gdk_window_add_filter(NULL, OnXEvent, NULL)`

Note that the API was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/89f6b8751e79ba597fcbd8292df377fa98a7319f) in GTK+ 4.x.